# Как прочитать значение из реестра?

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7, реестр

Покажите, как можно прочитать значение из реестра в Делфи? Например, при нажатии кнопки TButton отобразить его в TEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  sKey = 'Software\\RegDemo\\IntKey\\';
var
  rReg: TRegistry;
begin
  rReg := TRegistry.Create;
  with rReg do
  begin
    RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if KeyExists(sKey) then
      begin
        OpenKey(sKey,false);
        edt1.Text:=ReadString('ключ');
        CloseKey;
      end
    else edt1.Text:='';
  end;
  rReg.Free;
end;
```

все получилось

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример из [оф.документации](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_TRegistry):

```
uses Registry;

...

function GetRegistryValue(KeyName: string): string;
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    Registry.RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

    // False because we do not want to create it if it doesn't exist
    Registry.OpenKey(KeyName, False);

    Result := Registry.ReadString('VALUE1');
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Как вызвать эту функцию в обработчике нажатия кнопки и положить результат в TEdit, думаю, вы разберетесь сами.

Comment: procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  sKey = '\Software\RegDemo\IntKey';
var
  rReg: TRegistry;
begin
  rReg := TRegistry.Create;
  with rReg do
  begin
    RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if KeyExists(sKey) then
      begin
        OpenKey(sKey,false);
        edit1.Text:=ReadString('AVP');
        CloseKey;
      end
    else edit1.Text:='';
  end;
  rReg.Free;
end; сделал таким образом но ошибка = [Error] Unit1.pas(149): Undeclared identifier: 'edit1'

Comment: @delphi ну так `edit1` вы откуда взяли, он у вас на форме вообще есть?

Comment: да есть)) но когда нажимаю на Button в Edit не чего не показывает((

Comment: @delphi Если бы было, то компилятор бы не ругался. Значит вы что-то путаете. Если просто не показывает, то проверяйте отладчиком, почему код выполняется по else ветке (может ключ не так задали, или путь).